# How can I create a python networkx digraph on my hard drive instead of ram?

Tags: python, networkx

I am running a script to build a networkx digraph that will have over 5 million nodes. I am running trouble with my memory being full before the script is finished. Is there a way to create the object on my local disk and work with it there, rather than in ram?

Comment: You'd need to persist the graph, possibly as an edge list for instance if you can't create the entire network in memory, are you reading a text file in order to generate the graph or on the fly?

Comment: No, I am scraping wikipedia, the code is here: https://github.com/aws24689/wikiclicks/blob/master/WikiDump.py I am essentially trying to create a network of all wikipedia pages and the links in the body. The problem I have with creating a list of edges is that in my script, I query the digraph for the outermost nodes and scrape the urls from those

Comment: I'd set a chunksize/ node limit when scraping and write out: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.write_edgelist.html